# Error during visualization of many layers on Chrome (ExtJS, GeoExt, OpenLayers)

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js, chrome

I've noticed that on the latest version of Chrome (36.0.01985) my application crashes when a lot of layers are displayed (and/or the browser is maximized and the map is zoomed out). In particular, the panels are not shown at all and the map is only partially rendered. No matter the kind of layer (raster, vector), the problem is always present when there is a lot of data to render. The problem doesn't occur on other browsers. I've also tested it also on an older version of Chrome (26) and interestingly, there was no error.

I'm actually using ExtJS 3.4, GeoExt 1.1 and OpenLayers 2.13.1 (I know they are oldies, but till now they worked very well). 
I'm also wondering if an upgrade of these tools could solve the problem or only make me feel younger.

Tips?